# Linq check if value exists otherwise set default value

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

Hey I have the following query i.e.

```
    public int GetDefaultCurrencyForOrganization(string organizationId)
    {
        return (from a in _dataContext.allocations
                where a.organizationId.Equals(organizationId)
                select a.currencyId).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Which may return nothing for a lot of companies, and this was I want to set a value of 4 to return. Just wondering how I could add that to the above ?

Comment: So you want to return `4` if the query returns nothing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
public int GetDefaultCurrencyForOrganization(string organizationId)
{
    return (from a in _dataContext.allocations
            where a.organizationId.Equals(organizationId)
            select (int?)a.currencyId).SingleOrDefault() ?? 4;
}
```

You could also do this:

```
public int GetDefaultCurrencyForOrganization(string organizationId)
{
    var alloc = _dataContext.allocations
        .SingleOrDefault(a => a.organizationId.Equals(organizationId));
    return alloc != null ? alloc.currencyId : 4;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try DefaultIfEmpty(4) instead of SingleOrDefault to specify a value.:

```
public int GetDefaultCurrencyForOrganization(string organizationId)
{
    return (from a in _dataContext.allocations
            where a.organizationId.Equals(organizationId)
            select a.currencyId).DefaultIfEmpty(4).Single();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx

Comment: Getting an error when I use this Unsupported overload used for query operator default if empty

Comment: Instead of Single() can you try using First()?

Comment: What is the type of `currencyId`? If it is a string like `organizationId` then you probably want the string literal "4" instead of the integer 4 constant.

Comment: @devgeezer In the original question, the type of `GetDefaultCurrencyForOrganization` is `int` so we can assume that `currencyId` is also an `int`